# FastMember ObjectReader doesn't work with inherited interfaces

Tags: c#, fastmember

I get an interface as return from a library that I have no control over:

```
public interface IA : IB { String A { get;} }
public interface IB { String B { get;} }
```

Now when I try to run this code, I get an exception:

```
List<IA> list = library.Get();
IDataReader r = ObjectReader.Create(list, nameof(IA.A), nameof(IA.B));
while (r.Read())
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < r.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        //HERE ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: name
        Object o = r[i];
        Console.Write(o + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

It seems like it doesn't find the `B` property because it's declared in IB. I confirmed this by making a test and having B in `IA` directly.

I have found a very bad workaround, which involves creating a new class that implements IA:

```
public class Ab : IA
{
    public Ab(String a, String b)
    {A = a;B=b;}

    public String A { get;}
    public String B { get;}
}
```

and then convert the `List<IA>` as such: `List<Ab> newList = l.Select(e => new Ab(e.A, e.B).ToList()`, then `ObjectReader.Create(newList)`. ObjectReader seems to find the `B` property when I do this. But that seems very wasteful on resources (and a lot of code) to create this intermediary objects with the exact same content.

Any idea if it's possible to solve in another way that doesn't involve creating new objects?

Comment: You could always open an issue? This sounds like a plain old bug to me. Interfaces do require special attention because, internally, their members don't inherit the way they do for classes, but I should think FastMember is supposed to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I cloned the Repository of the FastMember Package, in the `TypeAccessor` class I changed line 265 from:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

to:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = GetPrpsInterfaces(type, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToArray();
```

The Implementation of the replacing function:

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPrpsInterfaces(Type type, BindingFlags flags)
{
      if (!type.IsInterface)
           return type.GetProperties(flags);

      return (new Type[] { type }).Concat(type.GetInterfaces()).SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties(flags));
}
```

I found here:
[GetProperties() to return all properties for an interface inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358835/getproperties-to-return-all-properties-for-an-interface-inheritance-hierarchy)

This worked for me.

Comment: FYI - I used your answer to create a PR for fast-member. There's an additional bit of code that needs to be changed at line 17 of MemberSet.cs -- it's the same kind of change. You can look at my PR https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/pull/63/files

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being late, I hope your request will be contained in the next version.